# Dynamic Class Attribute in Python?

Tags: python, class, dynamic, attributes

I'm trying to write a function for a class that takes a bunch of files and adds them to the class as attributes.

Right now I have some class `foo`, and another class `bar`. I want to essentially go through a list of strings (this is simplified), and add each of those strings as an attribute of `foo`, and each of these attributes will be of class `bar`. So `foo` has a bunch of attributes of type `bar`. Now I've done this using python's `__setattr__`, and that's worked fine. The real issue is that I need to set an attribute within `bar`, and I need to do this for each individual `foo` attribute.

So for now, I have a for loop:

```
for name in list:
  self.__setattr__(name, bar(a, b, ..))
  self.name.a = 123
```

Unfortunately, the attribute is read as "name" and not the value in the list. 
So I get an error like: `foo object has no attribute name`. 
What I need is some kinda of dynamic access. I know of `getattr`, but as far as I know, that returns a value, and I don't think is applicable in my case. Do you guys know of anything that would work here?

EDIT: I can also add the things I need to set as constructor arguments too. The reason I'd prefer not to do that is I think it kind of overloads the constructor, and makes it kind of cluttered, especially since the argument names would be rather long. That being said, I can do that if necessary.

Comment: Do you mean `getattr(self, name).a = 123`? It's not really clear why you can't pass `123` into the class, you may have larger structural problems. Also you should use `setattr` rather than calling `__setattr__`.

Comment: Yes you're right, I was over thinking things and was stuck with the concept of `self.name.attribute` for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the bar-instance in a local variable:

```
for name in list:
    bar_value = bar(a, b, ..)
    setattr(self, name, bar_value)
    bar_value.a = 123
```

Comment: Ah yes. I tried something similar, but made in a way dumber way. I completely overlooked this in my effort to over complicate things for myself.