# How to use a list of strings as variable names/object attributes?

Tags: python, class, object, variables, attributes

What I'd like to do is have a list of strings be used as attributes of an object when it is created. I've seen another topic discuss using a list of strings as variables by creating a dictionary, but this seems to keep the strings as strings, which won't work for me, I don't think. Here's what I would like to work. It's a DnD exercise:

```
abilities = ['strength', 'dexterity', 'constitution', 'intelligence', 'wisdom', 'charisma']


class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        for ability in abilities:
            self.ability = roll_ability()       #this is a call to an outside function
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's almost certainly a duplicate for this, but I'm having trouble finding a good one. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/30790947/1126841, but I'm not certain enough to close this as a duplicate myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setattr`:

```
def __init__(self):
    for ability in abilities:
        setattr(self, ability, roll_ability())
```

Comment: This is a bad practice to use global vars and specially in class initialization.

Comment: Pretend `abilities = self.abilities` is the first line, and that `Character.abilities` is a class attribute.

Comment: Or just pretend `abilities` is named `ABILITIES` indicating that it is supposed to be used as a constant. Global variables are only bad practice when they aren't constant; `Character` is also a global variable holding a reference to the class, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is for a D&D game, it's likely you will need to access the ability scores dynamically too; for example, a `saving_throw` method could take the name of the ability you are using to roll a [saving throw](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Ability%20Scores#toc_35). In that case, it is usually a better design to use a dictionary instead of separate attributes:

```py
class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        self.abilities = { ability: roll_ability() for ability in abilities }

    def get_ability_score(self, ability):
        return self.abilities[ability]

    def saving_throw(self, ability, bonus=0):
        return roll_dice(20) + self.abilities[ability] + bonus
```

Comment: I don't know. I'm doing it as an exercise on Exercism, so it has to pass their test, which I think looks for specific things. I'm not sure a dictionary would work.

Answer (score 0):

This can be yet another option to go with avoiding using global vars:

```
class Something:

    def __init__(self, *args):
        for ability in args:
            setattr(self, ability, roll_ability())


abilities = ['strength', 'dexterity', 'constitution', 'intelligence', 'wisdom', 'charisma']
s = Something(*abilities)
```